# ISIN does not count all dates in the list

Tags: python-3.x

I try to create a new column "federalgov" in a dataframe "fulldata" in Python, here is the code I use.

```
federal_gov_close=['2011-01-18','2011-01-26','2011-01-27','2011-08-23','2012-01-23','2012-10-29','2012-10-30']
fulldata[fulldata.index.isin(federal_gov_close)]

fulldata['federalgov'] = 
fulldata.index.get_level_values(0).isin(federal_gov_close).astype(int)
```

But I don't understand why only 4 days are actually counted in, as I check the results.

```
#count if dates are correctly coded.
fed = fulldata.groupby('federalgov')['date'].nunique()
print (fed)

federalgov
0    730
1      4
Name: date, dtype: int64
```

Comment: What does `fulldata.federalgov.nunique()` return?

Comment: @coldspeed it returns 2. I forgot to mention federalgov is a 0/1 dummy variable.

Comment: Sorry, I will need to see some concrete data.